# Ubuntu 16.04 - Software Updater shows blank update list, total size is still shown

Tags: 16.04, updates, update-manager

Firing up the Software Updater gives a blank list of updates, though their total size is still visible. Updates are successful as well, only the list of items on confirmation screen is blank white.

Any ideas what broke this? This may have something to do with the LTS point release, though I am not upgrading to 18.04 yet given GNOME problems. Also, I received the HWE kernel updates about a week ago.

Comment: I have the same problem for about 2 or 3 weeks now. I am on HWE a long time, so I don't think it's related to it. My conclusion was to install updates via terminal. As you said, it could be related to the point relase 16.04.05, but I don't know